# How to get "mysqlbinlog" utility for Ubuntu?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I can't find "mysqlbinlog" utility in my Ubuntu server, i can see mysql, mysqldump, mysqlshow etc... command line utilities but not mysqlbinlog utility.

Can someone please help me from where I can get this utility and install it?

Answer (score 4):

mysqlbinlog utility is in mysql server package. You should try install mysql server.

Comment: @Mahesh Patil mysql-server-5.5 in precise of architecture amd64: http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/mysql-server-5.5/filelist

Comment: I am using TAR package and it's installed using "MySQL-Sandbox"

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will figure it out. MySQL should include important utilities with generic TAR package as well.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned elsewhere in this thread, you should be able to see it using:

- using the `whereis` command

Also possible are:

- tab completion in bash
- using the `locate` command
- using the `apropos` command

Try this

```
cd /
sudo find . -name mysqlbinlog
```

If either

**a)** it's not in the same directory as your `mysqldump` &c., or

**b)** you can't find it anywhere using the command above,

Then there are two possibilities:

- You only installed the mysql-client package or
- something has **definitely** gone wrong with your install and you should uninstall and reinstall.

A list of the programmes (binaries) installed appears to be available [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/programs-overview.html). It's not very clearly worded:

> MySQL client programs that connect to the MySQL server:

but in the list that follows, there is no mention of `mysqlbinlog` whereas there is mention of the other utilities that you mention in your question.

Overall, in your case, the best thing to do would be to list the packages you have installed using [apt-get](https://askubuntu.com/a/17829), by for example using

```
apt list --installed | grep mysql
```

and uninstall them, then install the entire server package using

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

The reason I would uninstall the client first and then install the server is to avoid any potential version incompatibilties, although apt-get **should** take care of this.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you could try this command:

```
$ whereis mysqlbinlog
```

Answer (score -2):

`mysqlbinlog` is an impded utility inside MySQL server try to install MySQL server by executing the following command

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Comment: Welcome to [dba.se]! Your answer has been flagged as low quality by the system; please explain how this solves the problem stated in the question.